# Python program not looping/restarting

Tags: python, loops, easygui

I have a school assessment which is to make a child's spelling game, it has to loop/restart when the player clicks yes. So far when I test the game, the option/the easygui.buttonbox that asks the player if they want to play again and the yes/no options to play again or exit the game dose not appear. The program just closes after the player final score is displayed.

Here is my coding for the game, I can't find what I've done wrong and i had tried 3 suggestions to fix the coding and none of them have worked.

```
import easygui
#Childs Litercay Game
#Charlotte Lowe 03/09/2015

#Declare Constants and Variables
Score = 0
PlayerAnswer = 0
playOn = 0
while playOn != "Yes":
    playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Hey there, are you ready to test your spelling?", choices = ["Yes"])
if "Yes":
    PlayerName = easygui.enterbox ("Before we begin, what's your name?")

easygui.msgbox ("Hi " + PlayerName +"! Here are the rules of the game.")
easygui.msgbox ("There will be 3 words you can choose from, 2 will be incorrect and 1 will be right.")
easygui.msgbox ("All you have to do is select the correctly spelt word.")
easygui.msgbox ("For every right word you pick you will earn a point! There are 10 questions in this quiz")
easygui.msgbox ("Let's begin!")

PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices = ["Awesome","Awsome","Awesom"])
if PlayerAnswer == "Awesome":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("You're right! Your score is " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Awsome":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Awesom":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Becuse","Becus","Because"])
if PlayerAnswer == "Becuse":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Becus":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Because":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Correct! Your score is now " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Morning","Moring","Morening"])
if PlayerAnswer == "Morning":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Moring":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Morening":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Beleave","Believe","Belive"])
if PlayerAnswer == "Believe":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Beleave":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Belive":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Jewelry","Jewlery","Jewley"])
if PlayerAnswer == "Jewelry":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Jewlery":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Jewley":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Mispelled","Misspelled","Misspeled",])
if PlayerAnswer == "Misspelled":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Mispelled":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "Misspeled":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly    
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["acceptable","aceptable","acceptble",])
if PlayerAnswer == "acceptable":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "aceptable":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "acceptble":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["calendar","calender","callendar",])
if PlayerAnswer == "calendar":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "calender":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "callendar":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["equepment","equiptment","equipment",])
if PlayerAnswer == "equipment":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "equiptment":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "equipment":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["library","liebary","libary",])
if PlayerAnswer == "library":
    Score += 1
    easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "liebary":
     Score += 0
     easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
elif PlayerAnswer == "lieberry":
    Score += 0
    easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
if Score == 10:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, you got them all right " + PlayerName+ "!")
elif Score == 9:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, one away " + PlayerName+ "!")
elif Score == 8:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, so close "+ PlayerName+"!")
elif Score == 7:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, nearly there " + PlayerName+"!")
elif Score == 6:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, amlost made it " + PlayerName+ "!")
elif Score == 5:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, half way there " + PlayerName+ "!")
elif Score == 4:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, a little more pratice " + PlayerName+ "!")
elif Score == 3:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, pratice makes perfect "+ PlayerName+"!")
elif Score == 2:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, try again " + PlayerName+"!")
elif Score == 1:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, better luck next time " + PlayerName+ "!")
elif Score == 0:
    easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + "out of 10, better luck next time " + PlayerName+ "!")

while playOn != "Yes":
   playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Do you want to play again?", choices = ["Yes", "No"])
   if playOn == "Yes":
      Score = 0 #resets score count, if player wants to play again

   elif playOn == "No":
     easygui.msgbox ("Bye for now. Hope you'll play the game again soon!")
```

I'm hoping someone out in the world wide web can pick up on what I've done wrong. I'm very new to python so any help I can get will be so awesome. I know I have asked for help with this piece of coding before, but I only just made an account today, so I don't know how to reply to any comments or anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to play again if the user answers yes, you need to put the game in a `while` loop.  With minimal changes to your game, it might look like:

```
import easygui
#Childs Litercay Game
#Charlotte Lowe 03/09/2015

#Declare Constants and Variables
Score = 0
PlayerAnswer = 0
playOn = 0
while playOn != "Yes":
    playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Hey there, are you ready to test your spelling?", choices = ["Yes"])
if "Yes":
    PlayerName = easygui.enterbox ("Before we begin, what's your name?")

easygui.msgbox ("Hi " + PlayerName +"! Here are the rules of the game.")
easygui.msgbox ("There will be 3 words you can choose from, 2 will be incorrect and 1 will be right.")
easygui.msgbox ("All you have to do is select the correctly spelt word.")
easygui.msgbox ("For every right word you pick you will earn a point! There are 10 questions in this quiz")
easygui.msgbox ("Let's begin!")

while True:
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices = ["Awesome","Awsome","Awesom"])
    if PlayerAnswer == "Awesome":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("You're right! Your score is " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Awsome":
            Score += 0
            easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Awesom":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Becuse","Becus","Because"])
    if PlayerAnswer == "Becuse":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Becus":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Because":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Correct! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Morning","Moring","Morening"])
    if PlayerAnswer == "Morning":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Moring":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Morening":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Beleave","Believe","Belive"])
    if PlayerAnswer == "Believe":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Beleave":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Belive":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Jewelry","Jewlery","Jewley"])
    if PlayerAnswer == "Jewelry":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Jewlery":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Jewley":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["Mispelled","Misspelled","Misspeled",])
    if PlayerAnswer == "Misspelled":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Mispelled":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "Misspeled":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly____
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["acceptable","aceptable","acceptble",])
    if PlayerAnswer == "acceptable":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "aceptable":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "acceptble":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["calendar","calender","callendar",])
    if PlayerAnswer == "calendar":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "calender":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "callendar":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["equepment","equiptment","equipment",])
    if PlayerAnswer == "equipment":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "equiptment":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "equipment":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices =["library","liebary","libary",])
    if PlayerAnswer == "library":
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("Well done! Your score is now " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "liebary":
         Score += 0
         easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    elif PlayerAnswer == "lieberry":
        Score += 0
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is still " + str(Score))
    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    if Score == 10:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, you got them all right " + PlayerName+ "!")
    elif Score == 9:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, one away " + PlayerName+ "!")
    elif Score == 8:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, so close "+ PlayerName+"!")
    elif Score == 7:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, nearly there " + PlayerName+"!")
    elif Score == 6:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, amlost made it " + PlayerName+ "!")
    elif Score == 5:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, half way there " + PlayerName+ "!")
    elif Score == 4:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, a little more pratice " + PlayerName+ "!")
    elif Score == 3:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, pratice makes perfect "+ PlayerName+"!")
    elif Score == 2:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, try again " + PlayerName+"!")
    elif Score == 1:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + " out of 10, better luck next time " + PlayerName+ "!")
    elif Score == 0:
        easygui.msgbox ("You got a score of " + str(Score) + "out of 10, better luck next time " + PlayerName+ "!")

    playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Do you want to play again?", choices = ["Yes", "No"])
    if playOn == "Yes":
       Score = 0 #resets score count, if player wants to play again
    elif playOn == "No":
      easygui.msgbox ("Bye for now. Hope you'll play the game again soon!")
      break
```

### A simpler form

Computers are better at repetitive things than humans. The code below is modified to take advantage of that:

```
import easygui
#Childs Litercay Game
#Charlotte Lowe 03/09/2015

def play(choices, answer, Score):
    """Check spelling."""
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.buttonbox ("Which word is spelt correctly?", choices=choices)
    if PlayerAnswer == choices[answer]:
        Score += 1
        easygui.msgbox ("You're right! Your score is " + str(Score))
    else:
        easygui.msgbox ("Sorry Incorrect! Your score is " + str(Score))
    return Score
#    print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly

tests = (
        (["Awesome","Awsome","Awesom"], 0),
        (["Becuse","Becus","Because"], 2),
        (["Morning","Moring","Morening"], 0),
        (["Beleave","Believe","Belive"], 1),
        (["Jewelry","Jewlery","Jewley"], 0),
        # Fill in the rest.....
    )

congrats = {
        10:"you got them all right ",
        9:"one away",
        8:"so close",
        7:"nearly there",
        6:"amlost made it",
        5:"half way there",
        4:"a little more pratice",
        3:"pratice makes perfect",
        2:"try again",
        1:"better luck next time",
        0:"better luck next time",
}

# Hello and instructions
playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Hey there, are you ready to test your spelling?", choices = ["Yes"])
PlayerName = easygui.enterbox ("Before we begin, what's your name?")
easygui.msgbox ("Hi " + PlayerName +"! Here are the rules of the game.")
easygui.msgbox ("There will be 3 words you can choose from, 2 will be incorrect and 1 will be right.")
easygui.msgbox ("All you have to do is select the correctly spelt word.")
easygui.msgbox ("For every right word you pick you will earn a point! There are 10 questions in this quiz")
easygui.msgbox ("Let's begin!")

while True:
    Score = 0
    for choices, answer in tests:
        Score = play(choices, answer, Score)
        print(Score) #To check if programme is calculating score properly
    easygui.msgbox (congrats[Score] +" " + PlayerName+ "!")

    playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Do you want to play again?", choices = ["Yes", "No"])
    if playOn == "No":
      easygui.msgbox ("Bye for now. Hope you'll play the game again soon!")
      break
```

Notes:

- The code for giving the user three choices and updating the score now appears once in a function that is called many times for each set of choices.
- The code summing up the users performance is reduced to a few line which get the words of encouragement from a dictionary.

Comment: Thankyou both for your help, you both helped heaps, wonnderful people! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `playOn` to `"Yes"` in your first loop.

```
while playOn != "Yes":
    playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Hey there, are you ready to test your spelling?", choices = ["Yes"])
if "Yes":
    PlayerName = easygui.enterbox ("Before we begin, what's your name?")
```

At the end of the program, you are going into a `while` loop only while `playOn` does not equal `"Yes"`.

```
while playOn != "Yes":
   playOn = easygui.buttonbox ("Do you want to play again?", choices = ["Yes", "No"])
   if playOn == "Yes":
      Score = 0 #resets score count, if player wants to play again

   elif playOn == "No":
     easygui.msgbox ("Bye for now. Hope you'll play the game again soon!")
```

But, you set (and did not change) `playOn` at the beginning of your program to `"Yes"`, so the loop is skipped and the program ends.

---

A few notes to help you out

- "amlost made it"/"little more pratice"/"pratice makes perfect" - You have some spelling errors in your spell checker program.
- The program is very verbose and you have a lot of redundant code. You mentioned this was a school assignment so I'm not going to provide shorter code samples, but I'd encourage you to look up functions.
- Even fixing the main issue with `playOn`, clicking "Yes" isn't going to reset your program. You still need a way to get to the beginning of your spell check code (hint: functions again are your friend/alternatively an outer loop will also help)